# GUI Tests in Hudson (Jenkins) on Windows

Tags: graphical-user-interface, hudson, test, jenkins, maven

I will try to keep this question simple.  I've done much research on the topic, and haven't found any solution.

GUI Tests fail when doing maven builds on Hudson (Jenkins).  Hudson is running as a service, logged on as Local System.  I have enabled the service to interact with the desktop, but the tests are still failing.

The machine is a WinXP 64bit, but I have the option to migrate to Win7 64bit if that will fix this.

How do I get GUI tests passing during a hudson (maven) build?

Thanks

Comment: How do the tests fail? What does/does not happen? Can you run the tests manually if you cd to the Jenkins work dir and do a manual mvn verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/run-GUI-tool-on-windows-slave-td3477033.html), the only way to do so is to not run it as a service, but instead run it as a logged-on user, with a desktop.

Personally, I had luck with the following settings: 1) write a batch file to launch the slave via JNLP/javaws 2) put said script into autostart 3) set the user to auto-login.  This was all in a VM, so when I launched the VM it automagically registered itself as available to the hudson server.